# What's the name of the insert song in Charlotte episode 5?

Tags: music, charlotte

Does anyone know the name of the song that plays as Yu puts the headphones in and gets transported to the grassy field in his mind? The time it starts is just after 9:30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The song you're after is called 'Clouded Sky', and is performed by the band 'ZHIEND'. It is an insert song in episode 5 of the anime.

The scene where the song in question plays is viewable [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyklwyKHKLE).

The full song can be listened to [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuYTRaVvFiY).

Answer (score -1):

The song is called Clouded Sky by Zhiend (which is a band that exists in real life).

Comment: ZHIEND doesn't exist in real life. They're a fictional creation for the world of Charlotte. You can see at http://charlotte-anime.jp/music/zhiend/ that they're described as a 劇中バンド, meaning "band-within-the-show".